# Xamarin.Forms Android File Exchange, MTP

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, usb, mtp

I am trying to exchange files between a .Net Desktop App and a Xamarin.Forms Android app. I really had trouble getting resources and help, so I want this question to also wrap some stuff up - for other interested users (not only of Xamarin Forms)

So far I got to read files and folders in .Net C# using 
[Christophe Geers' Blog](https://cgeers.wordpress.com/?s=wpd) and [Fun with MTP](http://andrewt.com/2013/06/15/fun-with-mtp-in-c.html) and because writing did not work on all of my devices [Windows File Stuff by Flauschig](http://dev.flauschig.ch/wordpress/?p=212)

On Xamarin.Forms side of the wall I first stumbled over [Xamarin doc](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/) and [A lib to store from pcl code](https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage) and also [Plugin.Permissions](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/xamarin.plugins).

With all these sources above I was able to get reading and writing on the Android (Samsung A5, Android 6.0) to work. 
With [this description on filestructure](http://blog.wislon.io/posts/2014/11/20/xamarin-and-android-kitkat-and-your-external-sd-card/) I thought the following Code will always get a valid path:

```
public string GetExternalFolder()
    {
        GetPermission();

        var externalFolder = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path, "Android", "data", "com.exampledom.appname", "files");
        if (!Directory.Exists(externalFolder))
            CreateFolderStructure();

        return externalFolder;
    }
```

GetPermission() is taken from [Plugin.Permissions](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/xamarin.plugins) and will throw exception if permission is not given.

CreateFolderStructure() is using [pcl.storage](https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage)  - and looks like this.

```
private async void CreateFolderStructure()
    {
        try
        {
            IFolder rootFolder = await FileSystem.Current.GetFolderFromPathAsync(Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path));
            var subpaths = new[] {"Android", "data", "com.exampledom.appname", "files"};
            foreach (var dir in subpaths)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dir))
                    rootFolder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync(dir, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            }
            Log("Folder structure created!");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log("Folder structure cannot be created!");
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to log! " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Ok, now for the question: 
The Folder that is created by this Method is only created on one device I tested on (proof of concept) - all others (eg Samsung A3, Android 6.0) nothing happens(proof of helpless developer). A [reboot](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38282) is not the solution.
Also on the device this works on - the permission is requested as expected. There is no permission request on the other devices.

Why is the desired folder not created during install? It seems all other apps do have such a folder  'Android/data/com.exampledom.appname/files'.

What am I missing? It seems overly hard to import/export to android.

Comment: Again: First I'd like some hint of WHY the structure (which seems to be mandatory on android) is not created when installing the apk? ALL other apps do have their corresponding folder under 'Android/data' What do I have to do achieve that. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

@smack Does CreationCollisionOptions.OpenIfExists really create a folder? I don't think so. Is there not CreateIfNotExists enum?

Comment: Method is called 'CreateFolderAsync'. It does create folders. Also it works on one phone.